# Pink/purple glare inside the viewfinder on Canon EOS R6

Tags: canon, viewfinder, glare

I just got brand new Canon EOS R6.
Is it normal to see pink/purple glare inside the viewfinder (left side) while taking photos?

Answer (score 1):

No. I’ve had my R6 for 8 months and there is no glare, pink or otherwise) in the viewfinder. Initiate an exchange or repair while it is still brand new. I would try to have it replaced, since that sounds like it could be symptoms of another problem.

Comment: Thank you so much! I also realized that I am not fun of electronic vewfinder after all, despite all of its cool features.  Will return the camera. Do you have any recommendation for canon cameras with optical vewfinder, full frame? I am upgrading from canon eos 77D1! Thanks !

Comment: @Edyta, just FYI, "shopping questions" are basically not allowed here on stackexchange, since the information tends to be highly individual and time-sensitive. What SE is about is building a Q&A database that's good for everyone for as long as possible. You might have better luck asking on the  [dpreview forums](https://www.dpreview.com/forums); they're all about shopping questions. :) and can debate the relative merits of Canon 5D/6D series bodies with you.

Comment: ok, thanks so much!